# 別ファイルから呼び出した関数内のconsole.logが表示されない

Tags: javascript

```
<script src="hoge1"></script>
<script src="hoge2"></script>
```

hoge1の関数をhoge2で呼び出した場合、hoge1の関数内のconsole.logが動作しません。hoge2から呼び出した場合に動作するようにすることは可能でしょうか？

```
<script src="js/api.js" defer></script>
<script src="js/test.js" defer></script>
```

test.js

```
class Editor{
    constructor(){
        if(!(this instanceof Editor))return new Editor()
        this.currentTodoList = {item : null, todolist : null, time : null}
        this.wholeTodoList = {};
        this.timer;
        const ed = new EditData()
        
        this.pushStartBtn()
        this.changeInput()
        this.inputFocused()
        this.switchTimer()
        this.tabDelete()
    }
    pushStartBtn(){
        $(document).on("click", ".start", () => {
            let item_group = validationAndDataOrganize($(".item-group"))
            if(!item_group){
                console.error("validationAndDataOrganizeの返り値がない")
                return;
            }
            console.log(item_group)
            ed.setWholeData(item_group).setCurrentData()
            insert_dom({"dataset": item_group, "edit_process": "new_and_edit"}, )
        
            let first_val = Array.from(item_group.values())[0]
            let first_key = Array.from(item_group.keys())[0]
            console.log(first_key, first_val)
            console.log(item_group)
            this.wholeTodoList = item_group
            this.setTodoList({item : first_key, 
                                todolist : first_val[0]["todolist"],
                                time : first_val[0]["time"]})
            console.log(this.wholeTodoList)
        })
    }
```

api.js

```
function validationAndDataOrganize(jqueryDom){
    let item_group = new Map();
    let item_group__obj = Array.from(jqueryDom)
    const items = Array.from(jqueryDom.find(".item"))
    let choufuku = items.filter((x, i, self)=>{return self.indexOf(x) !== self.lastIndexOf(x);});
    if(choufuku.length) alert("項目は重複できません。");return false;
        consle.trace((items))
    if(items.some(x => !x)) alert("項目は必須です");return false;
    
    for(let w of item_group__obj){
        let vals = [];
        let input = Array.from($(w).find('.input'))
        let koumoku = input.shift().value
        let lists = [];
        console.log(input)
        let todoListArr = [];
        
        
        for(let i in input){
            if(i % 2 !== 0 && i > 0){
                let todolist = input[i-1].value
                let time = input[i].value
                console.log(todolist, time)
                //todolist && timeのバリデーション
                if([todolist, time].length > 0 && [todolist, time].length < 2){
                    alert("フォームはすべて入力してください。");
                    return false;
                }else if([todolist, time].every(x => !x)){//undefinedの場合
                    continue;
                }else if(time.length > 3){
                    alert('「勉強時間」は3桁以内におさめてください')
                    return false;
                }
                todoListArr.push(todolist)
                lists.push({"todolist":todolist, "time":time})
                console.log(todoListArr)
            }
        }
        if(todoListArr.length !== [...new Set(todoListArr)].length){//set　重複を除去
            alert("小項目は重複できません。");
            console.log(todoListArr)
            return
        }       
        if(lists.length){
            item_group.set(koumoku, lists);
        }
        console.log(item_group)
    }
    return item_group
}
```

Comment: 別ファイルかどうかにかかわらずconsole.log()が実行されれば表示されます。コードの問題だと思われるので、コードを提示してください。

Comment: ありがとうございます。api.jsのvalidationAndDataOrganizeをtest.jsで呼び出していますが、validationAndDataOrganize内のconsole.logがよびだされません。

Comment: 「validationAndDataOrganizeの返り値がない」のエラーが出るだけです。

Comment: HTMLコードも提示してください。まず確認すべきなのは`item_group__obj `が空かどうかでしょうね。

Comment: すいません。基本的なことでした。1行にまとめたくてif(choufuku.length) alert("項目は重複できません。");return false;としてましたが、ここでreturnされてました。

Comment: もし問題が解決したようであれば、コメント欄ではなく個別の回答として解決に至った情報を投稿してみてください。

Answer (score 0):

```
if() alert("項目は必須です");return false;
```

上記は以下のようになることを認識してませんでした、

```
if() alert("項目は必須です");
return false;
```